# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'dashboard' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<username>[^/]+)\\/$']

Tags: django, django-forms, django-authentication

I get this error

```
NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for 'dashboard' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<username>[^/]+)\\/$'].
```

After a users clicks the login button its expected that the url should redirected to 'domain/username.html', after it has been authenticated and move to the dashboard.html page.

login1.html

```
{% load custom_filters %}
<a href="" class="btn-back-sign-up" id="dismiss" id="sign-up">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"> &nbsp;SIGNUP</i>
        </a><br><br>
        <p class="text-join">Join our community that have more than 10,000<br> subscribers and learn new things everyday.</p>
        <div class='back' id='login_form'>
        <form id='login-form' method='post' {% url 'accounts:dashboard' %} ><br>
        {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                {% if field.errors %}
                     {% if form.errors %}
                    <p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>
                    {% endif %}
                {% endif %}
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ field.label_tag }}
                    {{ field|add_class:'form-control'}}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control input-upper" id="username" placeholder="Username" name="username" required id="id_username"><br>
              <input type="password" class="form-control input-upper" id="password" placeholder="Password" name="password1" required id="id_password"><br>
              <button type="submit" value='Login' id="top-login-btn" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-signup-form-1">LOGIN</button>
              <p class="text-center">or</p>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-sign-linkedin-1">Login up with LinkedIn</button>
              <p class="text-already">Don't have an account?
               <a href="" data-toggle="modal" class="btn-back-sign-up"  data-target="#modal-signup" id="dismiss" id="sign-up">Sign Up</a>
              </p>

            </div>
        </form>
        </div>
        <p class="text-already"><a href="{% url 'password_reset' %}">Forgot Password?</a></p><br>
```

views

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request, username):
    """Dashboard page for user"""

    if request.user.username != username:
        return redirect(
            'accounts:dashboard',
            args=(request.user.username,)
        )
    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard.html', {
        'notifications': request.user.notifications.order_by('-date_added'),
        'sub_token': url_crypt.encode_token((request.user.subscription.plan,))
    })
```

urls.py

```
name = 'accounts'
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'accounts/register', views.register, name='register'),
    path(
        r'accounts/account-activation-sent/', views.account_activation_sent,
        name='account_activation_sent'
    ),
    path(
        r'accounts/activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.activate,
        name='activate'
    ),
    path(r'purchase/<token>/', views.purchase, name='purchase'),
    path(r'<str:username>/deactivate/', views.deactivate, name='deactivate'),
    path(r'deactivated/', views.deactivated, name='deactivated'),
    path(r'<str:username>/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
    path(r'accounts/login/', views.user_login, name='login'),
    path(r'accounts/expired', views.expired, name='expired-account'),
    re_path(
        r'^(?P<username>\w+)/logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),
        name='logout'
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

from urls:

```
path(r'<str:username>/', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

means, you need to call the dashboard url with an username argument in template. You can fix it by in urls:

```
path(r'', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
```

and keep the template as it is.